# Disable pull down dismissal of SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is it possible to disable the pull down dismissal gesture of `SFSafariViewController`?

It seems like the `SFSafariViewController` runs in its own window, hence, setting [isModalInPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-ismodalinpresentation) or even setting the [presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiadaptivepresentationcontrollerdelegate/3229890-presentationcontrollershoulddism) doesn't seem to do anything.

The `SFSafariViewController` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) don't seem to specify anything here either.

MWE:

```swift
import SafariServices
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
           let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
            // `presentationControllerShouldDismiss` will be ignored, if isModalInPresentation is set to `true`
            // vc.isModalInPresentation = true
            vc.presentationController?.delegate = self

            self.present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        NSLog("Did dismiss")
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `vc.isModalInPresentation = true`

Comment: @jawadAli Yes. It’s commented in the MWE.

Comment: There is a difference, if the `UIViewController` is embedded in the `UINavigationCController`: https://contagious.dev/blog/modal-uinavigationcontroller-ios-13-dismiss-detection-uiadaptivepresentationcontrollerdelegate/.

However, this is not the case for `SFSafariViewController`.